# Martingale w.r.t. the filtration $\{\mathcal{F}_{t \wedge \tau}\}$

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, stochastic-analysis, filtrations

I want to show that any martingale w.r.t. the filtration $\{\mathcal{F}_{t \wedge \tau}\}$ is also a martingale w.r.t. the filtration $\{\mathcal{F}_{t}\}$.

So, suppose $(X_n)_{n \geq 0}$ is a martingale w.r.t. $\{\mathcal{F}_{t \wedge \tau}\}$. That is, $X_t$ is $\mathcal{F}_{t \wedge \tau}$-measurable and integrable and $\mathbb{E}[X_t | \mathcal{F}_{t \wedge \tau}] = X_s$ for $s<t$.

Since $\mathbb{1}_{\{\tau \leq s\}} X_t$ is $\mathcal{F}_{t \wedge \tau}$-measurable,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[X_t \mid \mathcal{F}_{t \wedge \tau}] &= X_s \\
\mathbb{1}_{\{\tau \leq s\}} \cdot \mathbb{E}[X_t \mid \mathcal{F}_{t \wedge \tau}] &= \mathbb{1}_{\{\tau \leq s\}} X_s\\
\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_{\{\tau \leq s\}}X_t \mid \mathcal{F}_{t \wedge \tau}] &= \mathbb{1}_{\{\tau \leq s\}} X_s  \qquad \text{(is this step correct?)}\\
\mathbb{1}_{\{\tau \leq s\}}X_t &= \mathbb{1}_{\{\tau \leq s\}} X_s.
\end{align*}
Then I want to show that $(X_n)$ is indeed a martingale w.r.t. $\{\mathcal{F}_{t}\}$. With $s<t$ and $A \in \mathcal{F}_s$,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_A X_t] &= \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_A \mathbb{1}_{\{\tau \leq s\}}X_t] + \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_A \mathbb{1}_{\{\tau > s\}}X_t] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_A \mathbb{1}_{\{\tau \leq s\}}X_s] + \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_A \mathbb{1}_{\{\tau > s\}}X_t].
\end{align*}
Where I got stucked... Why should we elaborate $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_A X_t]$? How is this related to $\mathbb{E}[X_t \mid \mathcal{F}_s]$ and how to find that this is equal to $X_s$?